# Load an image in R, with no external package

Tags: r, image

Is it possible to **load an image with R** (.bmp or .jpg or .png or anything else), but **without using an external package like this one** :

```
> library(png)
```

---

*Note: I don't want to require an external package, because it's for a course I'm teaching on university's computers where I think I cannot install package myself (and no time to ask sys-admin before the course...).

Thus, I'd like to load an image, but without having this error:*

```
Error in library(png) : there is no package called ‘png’
```

*because the package is not installed... This message was produced on my computer, showing that `png` seems to not be installed by default on Windows binaries*.

Comment: I know networked computers are occasionally locked down, but is it too much to suggest the students type in `install.packages("png")` on each computer they use? (It has no other dependencies so is not a bear to install.)

Comment: If everything works well, it *should* be good. But if networking fails or if the each student's computer in the classroom does not allow to install package, I'm stuck in the middle of my course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, here is a trick that allows to install packages on university computers that might have limited access:

```
setInternet2(T)
```

then:

```
install.packages('png')
library(png)
x = readPNG('d:\\photo.png')
```

Comment: `setInternet2` is defunct as of R 3.3

Comment: @HongOoi How to do it then with R 3.3 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you write an image to `.RData` file without using any dependencies, then yes. Otherwise no, you will have to meet all the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik. Would you have an idea for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859602/load-and-display-an-image-with-r-why-is-it-90-rotated?