# Load and display an image: why is it rotated 90°?

Tags: r

When doing:

```
library(png)
img = readPNG("a.png")
```

the image is loaded into a matrix and then by doing:

```
image(img, axes = FALSE, col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

it is displayed. However it is displayed 90° rotated like this:

[image]

**Why? and how to display it normally?**

I tried to transpose the matrix `img = t(img)`, but then it is flipped 180° vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this works - transpose and then flip the columns:

```
image(t(img)[,ncol(img):1],axes=FALSE,useRaster=TRUE)
```

The *reason* for this flipping is the difference between image contexts and tabular contexts: from `?image`,

> Notice that ‘image’ interprets the ‘z’ matrix as a table of
>        ‘f(x[i], y[j])’ values, so that the x axis corresponds to row
>        number and the y axis to column number, with column 1 at the
>        bottom, i.e. a 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation of the
>        conventional printed layout of a matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenBolker.